# Unable to set font in BaseAdpater class?

Tags: android, listadapter, baseadapter, android-assets, typeface

this is the getView function of classBinderData extends BaseAdapter:

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {`

```
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name); 
                   vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(vi.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Thin.ttf");
    holder.name.setTypeface(tf);    
    return vi;
}`
```

adding the line: 
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(vi.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Thin.ttf");

makes the app crash.

So how to set font?

### Edit

### LogCat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.myapp.BinderData.getView(BinderData.java:65)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2045)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4806)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1386)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:558)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4806)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:298)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:829)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:558)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4806)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:298)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2111)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12853)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1065)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2455)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what exception do you get. Also this operation is really heavy. Why dont you put inside the if (converView==null) ?

Comment: i tried both inside and outside if(converView==null).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View vi = convertView;

if (convertView == null) {
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name); 
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(vi.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Thin.ttf");
    holder.name.setTypeface(tf);    

    vi.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
}

     return vi;
}
```

`TypeFace.createFromAsse`t is an heavy operation. Do it once when you retrieve the `TextView` from your layout

Also be sure that inside the assets folder you have created the folder `fonts` and that it contains `Roboto_Thin.ttf`

Comment: What does heavy operation mean?

Comment: that requires more time and memory

Comment: Yea well actually I plan to add more elements to list item, not just the current lone text name. There will be an image and two other texts.

Comment: Creating typeface from assets.

Comment: what-s the content of the Assets folder?

Comment: Roboto-Bold.ttf Roboto-Condensed.ttf Roboto-Light.ttf Roboto-Medium.ttf Roboto-Regular.ttf Roboto-Thin.ttf

Comment: you have Roboto-Thin.ttf  and not Roboto_Thin.ttf. Also you should put inside assets/fonts

Comment: It is inside assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't allocate the typeface each time you create the view. Allocate once, and use that in every new view.

In that case, check out this topic, and try out the suggestions there:
[Null pointer exception while importing a font in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163668/null-pointer-exception-while-importing-a-font-in-android)

Comment: Oops. But the font name is correct. Now where do I get this stack trace from, in Eclipse?

Comment: You can see the error stack trace in the logcat window (Window > Show View > Other > Logcat). Filter this to your application, and the last lines written with red (starting with Uncaught exception: ) is the exception that caused the force close. In that you can find where and possibly why was the exception thrown.

Comment: There you go, the logcat. I can't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: Which is line 65? The one with creating the typeface, or the one setting it?

Comment: Creating typeface from assets